# Why unity makes one additional frame at the end of animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

im kinda new in unity, so don't laugh to loud
so that's the problem, when i made the new animation, i got one useless frame 61. The whole animation takes 60 frames
And due of this one last frame, animation is slows down at the end.

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwwoN.png)

Comment: Afaik this happens if you want to loop the animation but the final pose does not match the first one so Unity sometimes adds a filler frame

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with that too when I was trying to loop my animations smoothly.  I got around the problem by changing my animation clip to Frames instead of Seconds.  Then make sure to set your Samples to 60.  You can make that change by clicking on this

[image]